# Как теперь оплачивать apple developer license из России

Tags: ios, apple, платежи

В связи с текущими событиями в мире, Apple не может принимать платежи от российских карт Visa/Mastercard. Как можно продлить лицензию разработчика в кабинете Apple? Принимает ли Apple Union pay?